# Powershell command to get monitor count in hyper v

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I need to get the number of screens that are connected with hyper v (using windows 10). I have dual monitors connected and it is visible while using hyper v machine.

I need to get the screen count while using hyper v. Is there any way?

While running the command

```
@(Get-CimInstance -Namespace root\wmi -ClassName WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams).Length
```

in my hostmachine, I'm getting the count as 2. But when I run it in hyper v machine, I'm getting it as 1.